# remove navigation image from MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am doing update on of the project that was done 2 years back using nib files.

I see for navigation image, he have used

```
-(id)initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController
{

    self = [super initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
    if (self)
    {
        self.delegate = self ;
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top_bar_bg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        //[self.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    }
    return self ;
}
```

For email he have

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[picker setSubject:@"CarZone"];

// Set up recipients
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:dealerInfo.dealerEmail]; 
[picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
// Fill out the email body text
NSString *emailBody = @"Input your message here.";
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:^{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
}];
[picker release];
```

I tried to hide navigation bar using

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"text_field.png"];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES:

Also replaced `self.navigationController` with `picker.navigationController`

Still nothing...

How can I hide this menu? While sending, client don't want to see navigation. He want plain white screen or blue navigation as iOS 7/6 standard.

Any idea how to get this done for nib files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes UGLY is better way then NOTHING...

While sending I added below code...

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top_bar_bgwhite.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I am creating top bar with white background... :D :P

And in `didFinishWithResult` I switched back to original

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top_bar_bg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Ugly way, but can't handle it.

Note: For iOS 6, `top_bar_bgwhite.png` will be `top_bar_bgblue.png`

Answer (score 0):

you can try to set back image to MFMailComposeViewController only with

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MFMailComposeViewController class], nil] setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

and to make any manipulations with `UINavigationBar` of `MFMailComposeViewControllerm` you need to call soothing like `self.navigationBarHidded = YES;` cause **MFMailComposeViewController inherits from UINavigationController** directly, you don't need to access via self.navigationController